# Access Custom Preferences set on a PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

How can I access to the shared preferences set on a PreferenceActivity? It generates de proper XML on my shared_prefs folder, but when I access like

```
prefs=MatchappApplication.INSTANCE.getSharedPreferences("app_settings",
    Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
prefs.getBoolean("show_weather_notifications",true);
```

it doesn't work (returns true always, even if I change the value in the PreferenceActivity).

How I must to access this preference?

Thnks!

Comment: I only exits the Activity and it remains on the XML

Comment: I don't save. I only exiting the PreferenceActivity the preferences are saved on my app_settings.xml.

I need to save?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the error.

In my CustomPreferenceActivity, I must to setSharedPreferencesMode

```
PreferenceManager manager = getPreferenceManager();
manager.setSharedPreferencesName("app_settings");
manager.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_settings);
```

It works now!